# concrete5: how to define a new model and its controllers and views

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-5.7, concrete

I am newbie to `concrete5` CMS, I want to create a table named "books" which contains some books info, and I want to develop a CRUD controller of this table "Create, Update, Delete", then display it at the home page.

How I can do that? are there any useful tutorials or examples?

Comment: Are you building a block, or a package? Have you taken a look at the documentation/tutorials on C5's own site?

Comment: @NicolaiKrüger this the key of my question, I really wondering what I should build? block, or a package? I tried to build a block at first but it doesn't seems what I am looking for. just imagine a website that offers books and allow the visitors to display and search them. so what I should build ?!

Comment: Then I guess you would build a package, probably with some blocks included. But the main catalog should be stored in a database related to the package

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building a whole CRUD tool for this you could just create a Page Template, Page Type, some Page Attributes (the book information), and then a couple of blocks and custom templates to display your information.

So you would create a Page Type - Book, a Page Tempalate - Book which uses only the Page Type of Book.  You would associate your Book Attributes to this on the Composer Form, and then use your custom blocks and templates for front end display.